# Converting a continuous variable to categorical

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, binning

I have several continuous predictor variables and one binary outcome variable. One of these predictor variables has the following description using the Hmisc package:

```
> describe(dfhh$x1)
dfhh$x1
   n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd      .05      .10      .25      .50      .75      .90      .95 
7888        0     4863        1    41.67    19.79    20.26    23.22    29.14    37.14    48.57    63.61    77.40 

lowest :   0.000   8.246   8.797   9.616   9.841, highest: 248.542 250.113 283.178 338.605 354.072
```

I want to get some descriptive statistics out of this, such as an odds ratio to see what happens at one level relative to another. I felt that dichotomatizing this variable would aid in the objective at hand, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Comment: There's no set way to divide a continuous variable into categories.  Sometimes there is a logical cutoff.  For example, if you have a drinking water quality standard, you can classify observations as to whether they met this criterion or not.  Otherwise, you might divide a variable into quantiles or other groups of equal observations. The `cut2` function in `Hmisc` is a convenient way to do this.

Comment: @SalMangiafico so in the absence of a logical cutoff, just cutting into equal bins would be acceptable?

Comment: I think it really depends on the data and your purpose in categorizing it.  If categorizing into two groups, does it make sense to divide data into greater than  or less than the median?  If into five groups, does it make sense to break into quantiles?

Comment: The purpose would be to garner descriptive statistics and quantify the effects between levels of a given variable.

Comment: Right.  But a continuous variable doesn't have inherent "levels".  It only has the levels you assign to it if you have cause to do so.  So, there's no general formula here.  If it makes sense to break the variable into two, or into five, or into 10 categories, you can.  But in general, leaving it as a continuous variable preserves more information, and so is usually advantageous.  (Cont.)

Comment: (... cont) The exceptions that come to mind are 1) When there is a logical cutoff that is of interest, such as if a measurement meets a regulatory standard or not. 2) To categorize across a number of variables in cluster analysis. 3) To help simplify the data for presentation, for example if you talking about the top 20% of household income in a nation.  As a previous comment mentioned, you are probably better off leaving your dependent variables as continuous, and using logistic regression to determine the relationship to your dependent variable.  But as always, it depends on your purpose.

Comment: http://kevinmeurer.com/a-simple-guide-to-entropy-based-discretization/ follow this link, you will get there.

Comment: The key question here is: what kind of understanding do you want to get from your quantification? That "sort-of-largish cases are higher in some way than less-sort-of-largish cases, but are lower than even-less-sort-of-largish cases"? As opposed to "cases that exceed regulatory standards" or "larger than average cases" or some other meaningful partitioning? (The more foundational question is why bin the data at all? To use a method you're already familiar with? Binning coarsens your data and creates artificial distinctions. It's often a net loss unless the bins have actual meaning.)